How do I troubleshoot when a schema has the same name as a query?
How do I troubleshoot when a schema has the same name as a query?
For example:
SELECT
   date -- This keeps wanting to become the DATE function, even though there is a column called "date"

FROM
    bigquery-public-data.noaa.gsod.gsod2020

I've tried using quotation and apostrophes, but that hasn't worked.

SELECT T.DATE FROM  bigquery-public-data.noaa.gsod.gsod2020 AS T

Quotes will denote strings, its not like postgres in that regard. You can use the ` mark (I think its called a backtick) for telling bigquery to evaluate it properly, like
SELECT `date` FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020` 

